# How to retrieve parameter data from plugin in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm relatively new to WordPress.

I need to display data in a parameter field in the RecipeBox plugin, entered by the user, onto my page.

I'm a bit lost on how to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: You need (to be) a PHP programmer for this; if the plugin documentation doesn't explain this, all that's left is to read the plugin source and find out how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the page/post then inside `page.php` if you using page else if you using post then edit `post.php`  :  you should add the following line to echo the `field` inside the `while loop`:

```
$field_post = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'YOUR_FIELD_KEY',true);
echo $field_post;
```

the above will work to get the custom fields for the page or post and show them inside your post or page view  `get_the_ID()` will get the id of current post or page you are on and replace the `YOUR_FIELD_KEY` with which field you want to fetch.